# python setuptools installation in centos

Tags: python, centos, zlib, setuptools, mysql-python

i have to install mysqldb module of python in my centos server. i have 2 versions of python

1. 2.4.3 the default one
2. 2.6 which i installed

i want to install mysqldb module for 2.6 version of the python.
i installed it from [here](http://ben.timby.com/?p=123) but when i am on the line

```
python2.6 setup.py install
```

it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 5, in <module>
from setuptools import setup, Extension
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

so i went for installing setup tools from [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#id6).using the command

```
setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg
```

because i installed 2.6 python so i installed this rpm. but when i execute this command it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
```

but when i did locate command i do find the package and rpm installed for zlib.

```
/usr/share/doc/zlib-1.2.3
/usr/share/doc/zlib-1.2.3/README
/var/cache/yum/base/packages/zlib-devel-1.2.3-4.el5.x86_64.rpm
```

can any one please help me in this. I exactly want to install mysqldb module for python 2.6 i installed on my

```
/usr/local/bin/
```

directory.

any help or idea will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you installed Python 2.6, you most likely didn't have zlib-devel installed, so your Python doesn't have that feature built in. I recommend that you install

```
readline-devel
sqlite-devel
zlib-devel
openssl-devel
```

before compiling your own Python. After installing the newly compiled Python, fetch the setuptools source package and install it with:

```
python2.6 setup.py install
```

Comment: thanks for the help. my default python is 2.4.3 and every time i install these devel they will get associated to that python. how can i force it for 2.6 version python ?

Comment: These are system wide development packages for the C libraries and they have nothing to do with Python. When you are running the Python 2.6 configure script you can see if it has found the library headers needed for built-in zip support, ssl support etc.